# Why input() takes string and [input().split()] takes number?

Tags: arrays, string, python-3.x, list, integer

Code 1

```
n = input("Enter numbers:")
a = list(map(int, n.split()))
print(a[0])
```

Code 2

```
n = [input("Enter numbers:").split()]
print(ans[0])
```

Question 1: In code 1 I have to convert the string into int and in code 2 it's already in int. Why so?

Question 2 : the print code doesn't work. Why can't I print elements from list?

Comment: "in code 2 it's already in int" - that's completely wrong.

Comment: Do you know what code 2 is doing? Hint: It's not what you think.

Comment: It's taking input from user and splitting in with those spaces and adding to array??

Comment: The function of [] it to make list right!!

Comment: n = list(map(int, input(&amp;quot;Enter nunbers:&amp;quot;).split()))
print(n[0])
This works...
@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @user2357112 so what is it doing??

Answer (score 0):

In both pieces of code, you use the `input()` function. This function *always* returns a **`string`** from the user. Even if they enter numbers (integers) when prompted, this will return a `string` of those numbers.

I will now try to explain what each piece of code does with that `string`:

#### Code 1

```
n = input("Enter numbers:")
a = list(map(int, n.split()))
print(a[0])
```

Here, we assign the `string` to a variable `n`. Then, we take `n` and call `n.split()`. What this does is take the `string` and convert it into a `list` through splitting the inputted `string` on spaces. So if the inputted `string` was:

```
"1 2 3 4"
```

the `list` would be:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

We then apply the `int()` `function` to each `element`in the `list` using `map`. Next, we pass the `map object` into the `list()` `function` which converts it to a `list`. We are now working with a `list` of `integers` which is assigned to the `variable` `a`.

Finally, we `print` the first `element` with `a[0]`. So if the user, for example, had entered the `string`: `'1 2 3 4'`, it would `print` out `1`.

#### Code 2

```
n = [input("Enter numbers:").split()]
print(ans[0])
```

Here, we take the inputted `string` and immediately `split` it as before. This means we are now working with a `list` of `strings` got by splitting the `string` at every space.

However, as this is itself inside square brackets (`[]`), the `list` is embedded inside another `list`. So in the format (I'm not sure if this is how you intended the code to work):

```
[['1', '2', '3', 4']]
```

Then, you are `printing` `a[0]`. As `a` is an embedded `list` of the numbers as `strings`, taking the  first `element` will just give you the number `list`, not the first `element` of the number `list`. So our example of the input: `'1 2 3 4'`, would in this case `print`:

```
['1', '2', '3', 4']
```

Note that in this piece of code, we also didn't convert the numbers `strings` to `integers` so they remain as `strings` at the end.